# remove newlines from a .txt file with a simple cmd command?

Tags: cmd.exe, newlines

How do I remove newlines from a `.txt` file with a simple cmd command?

- This will erase the file:

  ```powershell
  findstr "{\r\n}" %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt > t.txt
  ```
- Whereas this will add useless information:

  ```powershell
  findstr "." %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt > t.txt
  ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102723/discussion-on-question-by-elisha-habinsky-can-someone-please-help-me-remove-newl).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are specifying the input file twice, so you are doubling your data.

If the aim is to delete empty lines, you were not far from the right command:

```
findstr "." "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt" > t.txt
```

Just ensure that your current folder is not `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt`,
or you will overwrite the input file.
You may alternatively specify a full path for the output file.

The following post might also help:
[How to remove newlines from a text file with batch or PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999562/how-to-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file-with-batch-or-powershell).

To totally remove all newlines, I used the following script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
for /f %%x in (test.txt) do set "row=!row!%%x"
echo %row% >newfile.txt
echo %row%
```

Here is how running the above script works:

[image]

Comment: thank you for that, i edited the question. now the code only does nothing(big imrovement i have to say). please take note as i also edited for clarity, that i want to 'merge' all lines into one. not just delete empty ones.

Comment: @ElishaHabinsky That is changing the question, not clarifying it. You should make a different question for that. And this website is for helping other people with the problem, so by changing it away from what it was, you removed the possibility of others being helped when they have that original problem. This is not a 'help the person asking the question site'   it is a question and answer site, and it produces a pool of knowledge useful for tech people.

Comment: @ElishaHabinsky So by all means, ask when you have a question but bear in mind tat it's not just for the one individual asking. So don't just change the whole question.

Comment: @DavidPostill i'm not going to argue with anyone. i'm happy to post another question if it helps people more that way. for the record, as of now (12 31 2019), there was only one answer provided that removed every occurrence of ' \r\n ' from a text document with cmd. the question does not say empty lines. it says new lines. '\r\n' is by definition a command to start a new line. therefore, removing new lines and joining lines is synonymous. furthermore, i believe that whoever undid my edit has done a disservice to the community. changing questions to fit answers is what it feels like to me.

Comment: @harrymc this answer only removes empty lines. all new lines with text are left as they are. can you provide a solution that removes 'new lines' a stated in the question

Comment: @ElishaHabinsky: Yes, the second script does that.

Comment: @harrymc it would be helpful if you  would show out put in you answer like the other answer. it did not work for me. this is why i'm asking

Comment: @ElishaHabinsky: Done. I'm still puzzled why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: you forgot to do 'type test.txt' i changed your script to from 'newfile.txt' to 'test.txt' and only then i got what i asked for. i changed my vote because it was your idea. your answer is now the closest to answering the question. the question implies making changes to a file which your answer does not. but you were very close so i applaud you. i don't think your commentary about 'specifying the input file twice' is necessary and it's completely off topic. please edit your answer. feel free to add a comment to the question. 'why my attempt failed' was not the question.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is to get some unix/linux/*nix commands on there.. and use the standard 'tr' command, examples all over the internet. `tr -d '\r\n' < input.txt > output.txt` would remove the \r character and the \n character and any \r\n sequence (or any \n\r sequence though there shouldn't be any such thing).  Cygwin has some commands.  The xxd command is good too, to see what is really in a file. Cygwin includes that.

Since an answer shows that it's possible to use findstr, that's ok..  but if I found myself having to do something really confusing looking with the cmd.exe 'for' command then i'd look for *nix style commands it'd probably have something simpler than 'for' for it, e.g. 'tr'!

Note- Some e.g. commenter ItWasn'tMe, aren't aware that you can use cygwin commands in cmd.exe outside of a cygwin shell, but you can.  Though nevertheless, the OP has commented to suggest that he is looking for a native solution, but OP should've put that in his question.

Answer (score 3):

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN (t.txt) DO @echo|set /p="%i" >> t2.txt`

- `FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN (t.txt) ..` will process the txt file line by line, `%i` being the whole line.
- `@echo|set /p="%i"` will echo the line without a new line ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433/6404321)).
- `>> t2.txt` will copy all output to a new file (efectively concatenating all lines into one since all newline characters were removed, as OP asked).

Result:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents>type t.txt
some line
SOME OTHER LINE
>
lolwut
Some Person
SOMEBUSINESS

SomeBusiness after an empty line
Users
Line with "quotes"
Wow look at this weird characters ÎøÎñÎ[{()}]ÖÎ¿Îö neat!
C:\Users\me\Documents>FOR /F "tokens=*" %i in (t.txt) do @echo|set /p="%i" >> t2.txt

C:\Users\me\Documents>type t2.txt
some lineSOME OTHER LINE>lolwutSome PersonSOMEBUSINESSSomeBusiness after an empty lineUsersLine with "quotes"Wow look at this weird characters ÎøÎñÎ[{()}]ÖÎ¿Îö neat!
C:\Users\me\Documents>
```

If you need the output file to be the same as the input file, you can then `move` (or `copy` or `type >` or...) `t2.txt` over `t.txt`. Example of how that would look in a single `.cmd` file:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN (t.txt) DO @echo|set /p="%i" >> t2.txt
MOVE /Y t2.txt t.txt
```

Comment: This is a good solution in/for the 2nd edit (removed by moderator), but, definitely, solve the second edition version, this I've tested, and 100% work/solve. +1.and, welcome to next future answer!

Comment: i think 'simple' strongly indicates native commands exclusively. this is the only solution that uses only native CMD commands and actually outputs the desired result as stated in the question. and i am speaking about the original question before edit.

Comment: @wallen considering that there is another answer that allows me to make the desired change in one .bat execution i feel that it is a better answer. what's nice about this answer is that it is a 'simple CMD command' like i asked. if you can do both maneuvers in one line i will reconsider.

Comment: Hi @ElishaHabinsky, I just accepted your proposed edit. Also, about providing a single .bat file: given that your question (the revision I answered to, at least) contained several advanced commands, including batch files and even PowerShell scripts, I figured you would put the two commands I mentioned into a `.cmd` file yourself, if/when needed. But I have no problem editing the answer to include it. Cheers!

Comment: @ElishaHabinsky I also decided to remove your original input file altogether to avoid sensitive info from spreading. I replaced it with arbitrary lines. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

---

- For **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** you can use:

```bat
((Get-Content ${Env:USERPROFILE}'\Desktop\tt\t.txt' -Raw) -replace "(?m)^\s*`r`n",'').trim() | Set-Content .\t.txt
```

---

---

> - ***Whereas this will add useless information:***
> - `findstr "." %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt` <strike>`%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt`</strike>`> t.txt`
>
>   ---

In fact, this command above can do this job, but, I'm considering that this not work, and I 
also suppose that your **`user name`** have space ("**compound name**" == "**Elisha Habinsky**")

---

- that make your command became look like this layout:

```bat
findstr "." c:\Users\Elisha Habinsky\Desktop\tt\t.txt c:\Users\Elisha Habinsky\Desktop\tt\t.txt
```

1) Use quote in **`"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt"`** and <strike>**`%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt"`**</strike>**`> t.txt`**

2) Don't need to use quote in **`regex`**`:`**<strike>`"`</strike>`.`<strike>`"`</strike>**

3) This **`.`** **means any character**, also space, tabs.

4) if your file have lines with only tabs in there? The lines blank is not 100% blank, so, these lines are saving to file output too!

5) Considering use a **`t.tmp`** file to do this job.

6) My suggest to you is use the code for bat in last lines code here, just copy these lines and save as **`file.cmd`**, the bat will remove all tabs in any line blank or not.

---

```bat
>.\t.txt findstr . "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt"

rem :: or ::

findstr . "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt"  >.\t.txt
```

---

For lines where have only tabs:

---

> - For command line(one line):
>
>   ---

```bat
for /f "delims= " %T in ('robocopy /L . . /njh /njs')do set "_tab=%T" && findstr . .\t.txt >"%temp%\t.tmp" && >.\t.txt (for /f tokens^=* %i in ('type "%temp%\t.tmp"^|find /v "%_tab%"')do @echo/%i) && del /q "%temp%\t.tmp"
```

---

> - For batch/cmd files:
>
>   ---

```bat
@echo off && SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims= " %%T in ('robocopy /L . . /njh /njs')do set "_tab=%%T"
findstr . "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\t.txt" >"%temp%\t.tmp"

>.\t.txt (for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('type "%temp%\t.tmp"
')do set "_line=%%~i"&& cmd /v/c echo/!_line:%_tab%=!
) && >nul del /q "%temp%\t.tmp" && endlocal
.\t.txt && exit /b || goto :eof
```

---

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>